# DataTable to XDocument - Out of memory error

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently trying to add a XML table schema to an API feed output and save it to the database. But when trying to convert the feed I keep on getting the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Code below:

```
 private XElement DataTableToXElement(DataTable dt)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument();
        using (XmlWriter w = xmlDoc.CreateWriter())
        {
            dt.WriteXml(w, System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema); //fails on this line.
            w.Flush();
            w.Close();
        }

        return xmlDoc.Root;
    }
```

To execute the above code, the code is below:

```
DataTableToXElement(DocsReponse.Payload);
```

The code works on small API feeds but hits an error on larger API feeds e.g. 1 GB+. Also this project cannot be compiled in 64 bit, so this is not an option.

Is there a way to fix the out of memory error in the code above, or should it be implemented differently?

Comment: Can you write directly to a file? dt.WriteXml("filename", System.Data.XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Comment: Do you want to write just the schema or both the data and schema?

Comment: I don't think writing to a file is an option and both the data and the schema

Comment: On small data sets it will work correctly, pushing the data in with the attached schema, example:

Comment: <NewDataSet>
  <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>